# Labeling Medical Image

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, labeling

I want to extract ground truth from my medical data. I'm looking for a program that can help with this. What I want to do is as follows.
I want to select a specific area and make it white, and I want it to be black in the other area. So I would have ground truth in my hand. There are examples in the pictures. Note: I dont have ground truth, only have original images without ground truth. I need to draw and extract this area from original image...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl6lR.jpg)Thank you for your help in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl6lR.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Let's split your image into its two constituent parts, first `image.png`:

[image]

and second, `mask.png`:

[image]

Now you can just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal without writing any code. You have a couple of choices. You can either:

- make the black parts of the mask transparent in the result, or
- make the black parts of the mask black in the result.

Let's make them transparent first, so we are effectively copying the mask into the image and treating it as an alpha/transparency layer:

```
magick image.png mask.png -compose copyalpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

And now let's make them black, by choosing the darker of the original image and the mask at each pixel location - hence the `darken` blend mode:

```
magick image.png mask.png -compose darken -composite result.png
```

[image]

Note that if you use the first technique, the original information that appears transparent is still in the image and can be retrieved - so do not use this technique to hide confidential information.

---

If you want to use the transparency method from Python with PIL, you can do:

```
from PIL import Image

# Read image and mask as PIL Images
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')
ma = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')

# Merge in mask as alpha channel and save
im.putalpha(ma)
im.save('result.png')
```

Or, transparency method with **OpenCV** and **Numpy**:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open image and mask as NMumoy arrays
im = cv2.imread('image.png')
ma = cv2.imread('mask.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

# Merge mask in as alpha channel and save
res = np.dstack((im,ma))
cv2.imwrite('result.png', res)
```

---

If you want to use the blacken method with Python and PIL/Pillow, use:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Read image and mask as PIL Images
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')
ma = Image.open('mask.png').convert('RGB')

# Choose darker image at each pixel location and save
res = ImageChops.darker(im, ma)
res.save('result.png')
```

---

If you want to use the blacken method with **OpenCV** and Numpy, use the code above but replace the `np.dstack()` line with:

```
res = np.minimum(im, ma[...,np.newaxis])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I don't have mask images and I only have original images. I want to choose a field in this picture and I want to make this white and the rest black. So I want to manually mask a image without a mask. The imageI want to do is shown in the picture. enter image description here. the area where I want to select red lines and I want to make it white inside, the other area is black. Paint can do this but it takes a few processesand takes much time. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can highly recommend [ITK - SNAP](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php) for this task. You can manually label your input images with certain labels (1 for foreground, 0 for background in your example) and export the groundtruth very comfortably.